# Use webdriver,python,beautifulsoup to retrieve dynamic website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, beautifulsoup

Trying to change the sort form the default (most relevant) into the "newest", something wrong and I can't save the page. Any suggestions?

```
#start webdriver to open the given product page via chrome browser
driver =webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371')
time.sleep(2)


#find the drop down list, then select the newest option and click  
m=driver.find_element_by_id("BVRRDisplayContentSelectBVFrameID")
m.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='http://homedepot.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/1999m/205080371/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml&amp;sort=submissionTime']").click()
time.sleep(2)

#save the search result into the python
html = driver.page_source
file_object = open("samplereview.txt", "a")
file_object.write(str(html))
file_object.close( )
time.sleep(2)

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)

#quit from driver
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two key selenium-specific things:

- do not use `time.sleep()` - use [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html)
- use [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) when dealing with `select/option` - it provides a very nice abstraction

Here is the modified code (look how readable and short it is):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371')

# waiting until reviews are loaded
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'BVRRDisplayContentSelectBVFrameID'))
)

select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('Newest')
```

And now I see the reviews sorted from newest to oldest:

[image]

---

To parse the reviews you don't necessarily need to pass the page source to the `BeautifulSoup` for further processing - `selenium` itself is powerful in locating elements:

```
reviews = []
for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@itemprop="review"]'):
    name = review.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]').text.strip()
    stars = review.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@itemprop="ratingValue"]').text.strip()
    description = review.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@itemprop="description"]').text.strip()

    reviews.append({
        'name': name,
        'stars': stars,
        'description': description
    })

print(reviews)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {'description': u'Very durable product. Worth the money. My husband loves it',
     'name': u'Excellent product',
     'stars': u'5.0'},

    {'description': u'I now have all my tools in one well organized box instead of several boxes and have a handy charging station for cordless tools on the top . Money well spent. Solid box!',
     'name': u'Great!',
     'stars': u'5.0'},

    ...
]
```

Comment: But how to save the new page into the beautifulsoup?

Comment: @plainvanilla why do you need to use `BeautifulSoup` - you can locate the elements using `selenium`, it is very powerful. What data do you want to extract?

Comment: I want to save the updated webpage into beautifulsoup, then extract the information like date of review, star. And finally output them to the excel.

Comment: Awesome!!! One last question, Can I retrieve the itemreviewed in the itemprop content?